# ZenCart product_info.php Quantity Box

Tags: zen-cart

I'm hoping someone out there can help me with this.  I tried posting it in the zencart forum, but no takers yet - so I'm hoping stackoverflow will be able to help.

In zencart, I've found that the product_info page can display minimum, maximum, and product quantity units.  However, it displays it "side by side". 
[Click to see the image.](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NmHDeVowEyaf0JcI0Hn0aw?feat=directlink)

I would like to have it displayed as a list item instead, but I'm at a loss on how I can do this.

The furthest I've got is narrowing it down to the tpl_product_info_display.php and in it, I found that it's caused  by

```
$the_button = zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display((int)$_GET['products_id'])
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those that were also wondering about this... someone managed to answer it in the [zen-cart forum](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1048540&posted=1#post1048540).

Head to includes -> Functions - Functions.php (in my case, I found it in functions_prices.php)

Then look for "zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display" function.

Change the following:

```
if ($check_min != 1) {
    $the_min_units .= PRODUCTS_QUANTITY_MIN_TEXT_LISTING . '&nbsp;' . $check_min;
  }
```

To:

```
if ($check_min != 1) {
    $the_min_units .= PRODUCTS_QUANTITY_MIN_TEXT_LISTING . '&nbsp;' . $check_min . '<br />';
  }
```

Adding the end, simply creates a new line, getting rid of displaying the units "side by side".

Comment: you can mark your own answer as  the correct answer so people can tell at a glance that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Yeah, I will, as soon as I'm able to. It's telling me I can do that in two days. :/